# How to store multiple variable values in Python

Tags: python

I need to store a random initial value so it could be used later after the user enters an override. So I have to use two variables to handle the same type of data. Later it is leading to unavoidable if/elif I would like to avoid.

```
var01='default'
var02=None
if var01: print var01
elif var02: print var02
```

Question: Since the incoming initial value every time's different no defaults could be used. Ideally an initial value would simply be 'moved down data-hierarchy' and remains 'there' available. If that is not possible I would like to see how a similar situation handled properly.

Comment: Can you not use a `list`?

Comment: Sure... or dictionary... But I need a single variable solution. Or some other but elegant.

Comment: Is a `list` not a single variable? Is it not elegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `list`:

```
var_list = ['default']
print var_list[-1] # 'default'
var_list.append('new var')
print var_list[-1] # 'new var'
```

Comment: So to be list! Thanks!